# Как преобразовать координаты для Яндекс.карт

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите, как корректно преобразовать имеющиеся координаты для работы с Яндекс.картами.
Запрашиваю координаты из input, координаты верные, но карта не отображает место. В консоли значение NaN, alert выводит как положено (00.000000, 00.000000).
Код:

```
var coordinates = document.getElementById(id).value;
ymaps.ready(map_init);
var myMap, myPlacemark;
function map_init()
{
        alert (coordinates);

    myMap = new ymaps.Map ("map", {
        center: [coordinates],
        zoom: 11,
        controls: ['fullscreenControl']
    }); 

    myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
    myMap.controls.add('zoomControl', {
        position: {
            top: 10,
            left: 10
        }
    });

    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([coordinates], {
            hintContent: [],
        }, {    
            iconColor: '#000000'
        });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

}
```

Comment: Точка же должна быть массивом из двух элементов, а вы туда суете массив с одним элементом.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо!
Разбил строку, уложил в массив:

```
    var coordinates = document.getElementById(id).value.split(', ');
```

Убрал кв.скобки в коде карты.
Все работает.